# Node js - Redirect to url with post data like form

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms

I am new to NodeJS . I want to send data to page with redirect multiple parameters like html form as below :

```
<form action="https://example.com/payment.aspx" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="Amount" value="5000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="ResNum" value="sdsadasd231323"/>
    <input type="submit" id="startBankPayment" class="btn btn-lg btn-success col-md-5" value="startPayment"/>
</form>
```

I need a sample code send data to url and redirect to this url like form submit button clicked ?

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Please give exact problem statement and issues you are facing ?

Comment: My question is edited .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function submitForm(){
var a = document.getElementById('Amount').value;
var b = document.getElementById('ResNum').value;
var holder = {Amount : a, ResNum : b};

 var xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr1.open('POST', "https://example.com/payment.aspx", true);
    xhr1.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.status == 200 && this.readyState == 4) {
            //ADD CODE to redirect my page when I get my data back
      }//
      };//end onreadystate
     xhr1.send(JSON.stringify(holder));//the object you are sending
}
```

Here is a sample that should help. You execute this function when your button is clicked, so you need to add the `click="submitForm()"` to your button. You also need to add `id="Amount"` and `id="ResNum"` to those fields. You also wouldn't need the form action anymore since this takes care of the actual post. You also need to know how the form is being read on the server end and what type of encoding you need. You may be able to send as form encoded data or you may need to JSON.stringify() the object before you send it off incase it is parsed as jsonencoded data, which I included.

Comment: Thanks but i don't have any form , i want redirect to a page (asp.net page) with post data without form in Back-End .

Comment: After some search i find "res.redirect" but this not send body post data . I need a function like "res.redirect"  that send an object to redirected page .